# Reversing a long in c#

Tags: c#, reverse, long-integer

I know in java that you can simply reverse a long (101010100000001) by using long.reverse (100000001010101). However, is there anything like these that exists in c#.

Comment: You can reverse the bytes by calling BitConverter.GetBytes, Array.Reverse, then BitConverter.ToInt64.  See the MSDN description of BitConverter for an example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Could you update your post to clarify exactly what you want to reverse? It seemed to me as you want to reverse the order of the _bits_, but some of the answers here seem to answer how to reverse the _bytes_.

Comment: @GrantWinney You should post your comment as an answer. Even if it's not the option for OP, it might be for someone else with a similar problem in the future.

Comment: [Bit Twiddling Hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html)

Comment: Java's `Long.reverse` (mentioned by OP) reverses the bits exactly as in the OP's example. `Long.reverseBytes` reverses the bytes. Why are they being downvoted? The 3 reasons given to close are bogus.

Comment: @DanielEarwicker My understanding from this question is **a)** *Find me docs to do the same in c#* OR **b)**  *Write it for me I am too lazy to research* , So this  is why I downvoted.

Comment: @EZI - I wonder what you think the purpose of Stack Overflow is?

Comment: @DanielEarwicker I would expect some research and code. Otherwise, this site would be *HireACoder.com*

Comment: It's a Q&A site. It's perfectly valid for someone to ask a simple question, especially if they go to the effort of clarifying exactly what they mean as the OP did here. The whole purpose of SO is to become a repository of such clear, straightforward questions and their answers, so others can find them in the future by googling. Please stop voting down valid questions.

Comment: @DanielEarwicker  Your statements like `It's perfectly valid` doesn't make it valid. `Please stop voting down valid questions` I'll continue to do it if I think a question is not valid for SO. Understood?

Comment: Of course you will. All I can do is explain to you that you've misunderstood the purpose of a Q&A site, and hope that you'll eventually become bored of your incredible power to downvote questions.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is no.  However it is achievable by code.
How about this...

```
    public static long RevLong(long l)
    {
        long tmp = l;
        long r = 0L;

        if (tmp < 0)
            tmp *= -1;

        while (tmp > 0)
        {
            r = (r * 10) + (tmp - ((tmp / 10)) * 10);
            tmp = tmp / 10;
        }

        return r * (l < 0 ? -1 : 1);
    }
```

Comment: this is slower than making long a string and reverse and parse back to long, I tested with this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29263007/1818723 and parsed back to long, and on 1M iterations I have x2 diff. Long to str to long took 00:00:00.1527619 and your solution 00:00:00.3237875

Comment: Nice!!  I didn't even think about that.

Answer (score 1):

How about...

```
public ulong Bit(ulong x, int n)
{
    return (x & (1 << n)) >> n;
}

public ulong ReverseBits(ulong x)
{
    ulong result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
        result = result | (x.Bit(64 - i) << i);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another aproach for reversing a long is:

```
    long num = 123456789;
    long reversed = 0;
    while (num > 0)
    {
        reversed = (reversed * 10) + (num % 10);
        num /= 10;
    }
```

or

```
long num = 123456789;
long reversed = 0;

while (num > 0)
{
    reversed = (reversed << 1) + (reversed << 3) + (num & 1);
    num >>= 1;
}
```

or

```
 public static long ReverseBits(long number)
    {
        long result = 0;
        const int numbersOfBitsInLong = sizeof(long) * 8; //Could be set to 64
        for (var i = 0; i < numbersOfBitsInLong; i++)
        {
            result <<= 1;
            result |= number & 1;
            number >>= 1;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

There are some interesting examples [here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/reverse-bytes/).  You could adapt one of these into an extension method, like so:

```
public static class LongExtension
{
    public static ulong Reverse(this ulong value)
    {
        return (value & 0x00000000000000FFUL) << 56 | (value & 0x000000000000FF00UL) << 40 |
               (value & 0x0000000000FF0000UL) << 24 | (value & 0x00000000FF000000UL) << 8 |
               (value & 0x000000FF00000000UL) >> 8 | (value & 0x0000FF0000000000UL) >> 24 |
               (value & 0x00FF000000000000UL) >> 40 | (value & 0xFF00000000000000UL) >> 56;
    }
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
ulong myLong = 3L;
ulong reversed = myLong.Reverse();
```

Comment: This reverses *bytes* not *bits*

Comment: Agree with @EZI not what is requested

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will work

```html
string s = 101010100000001.tostring();
char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse( charArray );
    return new string( charArray );
```